# Replacing (or re-implementing?) std::function for some statistics and testing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, c++17, dynamic-import

I've got a special case, where I'd like to measure statistics about my std::function usage. Usually things like time spent, amount of calling, which function is called often and also sometimes for testing like randomly throwing nullptr to check how my code handles it.

First I was thinking about inheriting from std::func and then override the function which retrieves the pointer - or someting like this - but after reading several topics and guides I came to the conclusion it's very unadvised.

My second thought is to simply create a wrapper class. Refactoring my whole code to use this wrapper instead of std::function wouldn't be hard to do, so it's okay. All I want to avoid is to use unnecessary and uncomfortable usage, like any extra function. eg.:

```
std::function<...> dummyvar (...);

// Later I can call this dummy var as simply as dummyvar(...)
// I don't want to add extra complexity, like this:

CustomWrapper<...> customdummy (...);
customdummy.getVal()(...);

// Best would be if I could actually "simply" replace all std::function to the Custom Wrapper.
```

---

In my current very simple case no copying of an std::function occurs, only simple initializing it once, the call it all the time when necessary. So if it helps you can have regard this and ignore other things like copy-constructor or so *(of course the more feature the custom implementation isn't lacking it's the better, but personally what I mentioned is far enough)*

---

I don't have any idea how to progress on, that's why I didn't even attach any source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename Sig>
class CustomWrapper
{
private:
    std::function<Sig> f;
    mutable std::size_t nbCall = 0;
    // ...
public:
    CustomWrapper() = default;

    CustomWrapper(const CustomWrapper&) = default;
    CustomWrapper(CustomWrapper&&) = default;
    CustomWrapper& operator=(const CustomWrapper&) = default;
    CustomWrapper& operator=(CustomWrapper&&) = default;

    template <typename T,
              std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<CustomWrapper, std::decay_t<T>>::value
                  && std::is_constructible<std::function<Sig>, T&&>::value, bool> = false>
    CustomWrapper(T&& arg) : f(std::forward<T>(arg)){}

    template <typename ... Ts,
              std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Ts) >= 2)
                  && std::is_constructible<std::function<Sig>, Ts&&...>::value, bool> = false>
    CustomWrapper(Ts&& ... args) : f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...){}

    template <typename ... Ts>
    auto operator ()(Ts&&... args) const -> decltype(f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))
    {
        ++nbCall; // Statistics you want
        // ...
        return f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    std::size_t getNbCall() const { return nbCall; }
    // ...
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f4485545170fd62)

Comment: I was struggling compiling your source for quite long, when I realized it seems to be only working on clang. GCC and VC has issues with __stdcall parameter in the function definition. Do you know any workaround for the problem?

Comment: @Unc3nZureD: I fix some typo, and provide link demo. So work on gcc/clang.

Comment: Do you use explicitly `__stdcall`?

Comment: Windows APIs I'm dynamically linking to are using stdcall, so I can't change them. Here's how I want to use it: https://godbolt.org/z/X9SLWX Did I try something wrong?

Comment: Works with correct parameters: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/p0Lz8E). As I used forwarding references, `NULL` is `0` so `int` (whereas pointer are expected for some parameters). specialization may allow to mimic `std::function` behavior, but with extra copies/moves

Comment: Ahhh, so the problem wasn't with the stdcall. I still have to get used to the error messages the cpp compiler gives when dealing with templates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the idea that you can use to create a wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
class CustomWrapper;

template <typename Result, typename ...Args>
class CustomWrapper<Result(Args...)>
{
public:
    template <typename ...SomeArgs>
    CustomWrapper(SomeArgs&&... args)
     : func(std::forward<SomeArgs>(args)...) 
    {
    }

    CustomWrapper(const CustomWrapper&) = default;
    CustomWrapper(CustomWrapper&&) = default;

    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::function<Result(Args...)> func;
};

void foo()
{
    CustomWrapper<void(int, int)> func([](int x1, int x2) {});
    func(1, 2);
}
```

I didn't implement all the methods, but it's quite easy to add them having this as a sample.

But also I want to mention that if you're calling `std::function`s very often - the best idea is to get rid of `std::function` itself to improve the performance. Consider switching to functional objects if possible in your case.

Comment: Care with template constructor, `CustomWrapper(CustomWrapper&)` would match your template resulting in invalid code.

Comment: @Jarod42, Yes your're right copy and move constructor should be implemented separately

Comment: I meant template constructor should be protected, or you have to provide all variants of copy/move constructor (regular `C(const C&); C(C&&)`, but also `C(C&); C(const C&&)` (and I ignore `volatile` cases).

Comment: I've just tried this and failed to compile dynamic imports: https://godbolt.org/z/vNo4zv - Probably one of the constructors are missing, but I'm yet weak to find what exactly :)

Comment: @Unc3nZureD, looks like the problem is with __stdcall. std::function in a MSVS standard library somehow stores the calling convention, while my implementation - not

Comment: Wow, intersting. GCC doesn't even accept my function type, clang compiles perfectly and Visual Studio fails to compile probably because of the stdcall stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to be constantly checked for statistics or only once before your program is shipped ? If only once I would recommend using profiler/coverage tools to see how many times function is referenced.

If you need constant statistics you need to look at std::function interface (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and create new implementation for that - it is not really that hard to implement.

Comment: For some special build I want to contantly monitor it :) So the rewrite seems to be the only reasonable solution to me :(